# python pyplot x axis comments

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently generating a plot of the form:

[image]

What I want to add is on the bottom axis I want to write some text, as each point has some different settings. For example at point 0 I would like to write (angling down as the text is long) true, true, true, true then at point 1 true, true, true, false, ... , false, false, false flase.

Can someone please explain how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you just make that text the x-axis tick labels, or do you need something other than that, and if so, what exactly?

Comment: When I try to use xticks I get an error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` using `plt.xticks(["True"])`

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `xticks`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation for set_xticklabels](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels).  What you want is something like:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(['true true true...', 'true true false...', ...], rotation=45)
```